# Почему публикация ответов, созданных GPT и ChatGPT, недопустима?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, справка, генеративный-ии

Несколько недель назад, исследовательская группа OpenAI опубликовала модель под именем ChatGPT. Эта модель способна генерировать тексты, которые выглядят как будто написаны человеком в ответ на запросы, написанные на естественном языке. Модель выдает какой–то результат на большой спектр задаваемых вопросов, в том числе на вопросы связанные с программированием. Этой особенностью воспользовались несколько участников "Stack Overflow на английском". К сожалению, сгенерированные тексты в основном оказываются не верны. Англоязычное сообщество [решило запретить публикацию сообщений, созданных GPT и ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/564240).

Мы видим, что данную технологию начали применять и на "Stack Overflow на русском". Как результат, вместе с командой модераторов мы подготовили новую справочную страницу:

> [Почему публикация ответов, созданных GPT и ChatGPT, недопустима?](/help/gpt-policy)

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что в случае публикации содержимого, созданного с использованием GPT и ChatGPT моделей, модераторы могут заблокировать учётную запись автора сообщений на срок до одного месяца.

Будем рады услышать ваши мысли!

Comment: Коля, привет. Когда выборы? А то модераторы тревоги по этим самым GPT аккаунтам никак обработать не могут.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Привет! Обычно, выборы в модераторы происходят по запросу текущей команды модераторов. Пока запроса не поступало. Думаю, стоит обсудить с ними необходимость.

Comment: Обычно... Всё давно уже далеко не обычно. Ну и чего тут обсуждать - видно ж всё и так по тревогам подвешенным.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ так мы обсуждали эту ситуацию, что и привело к появлению этого поста.

Comment: А как понять, сгенерировано оно автоматически или нет?

Comment: @Nofate да, ладно, обсуждали. На большом SO вердикт вынесли, я ссылки привёл в тревоге. Странно ожидать, что политика ruSO может пойти вразрез с генеральной линией партии по такому злободневному вопросу.

Comment: Я думаю, что затягивание с решением данного вопроса катастрофично. Люди, которые сами не дали не одного ответа, уже допущены к голосованию и проверкам. И что они наголосуют одному богу известно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ и? нельзя банить людей ссылаясь на правила другого подсайта.

Comment: @СергейКох "И что они наголосуют одному богу известно". Богу и команде модераторов. В случае нашего пользователя, который запостил 37 ответов за час, причин для беспокойства нет.

Comment: @maestro на данный момент сгенерированные тексты имеют некоторые характерные особенности. Ну и ответы на самые разные темы раз в две минуты не добавляют доверия.

Comment: А, то есть тот всезнайка, которого я тревогал за слишком водянистые ответы, был нейросетью? Я не заподозрил подвоха 

Comment: Осталось натравить ИИ задавать вопросы... А потом просто выделить им свой сайт для переписки :) Интересно бы, кстати, посмотреть примеры...

Comment: @Harry, здорово  было бы сделать этот сайт на платной основе (можно в биткоинах) (ага, я (мизантроп такой) осознаю, что приоткрываю запретный ящик)

Comment: На Хабре ChatGPT заставили поразгадывать русские загадки) https://habr.com/ru/post/707548/comments/

Comment: На английском Stack Overflow идет волна не только ответов, но уже и вопросов созданных ChatGPT, что приводит к затруднению помощи реальным людям и возможно в скором времени полному коллапсу Stack Overflow. Нужно более тщательно проверять вопросы от новичков и тех, кто появился в декабре. Да поможет нам бог!

Comment: Похоже еще один пользователь нейросетей - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/533449/versetty777

Answer (score 22):

Я резко против использования текстов сгенерированных с помощью ChatGPT (или подобных ему сервисов) в качестве ответов на Stack Overflow на русском.

Такие ответы часто некорректны (хотя выглядят на первый взгляд прилично), создают огромную нагрузку на модераторов и голосующую часть сообщества и, в целом, не то, что ожидают увидеть пользователи, задающие здесь вопрос.

- Если ответы сгенерированные ChatGPT чаще всего¹ плохие -> их стоит запретить (потенциальное количество таких ответов делает "модерацию голосованием" очень сложным).
- Если такие ответы в основном¹ хорошие -> тогда такое ответ пользователь мог бы получить сам, спросив у ChatGPT, так же как сейчас можно ввести поисковых запрос в Гугле или Яндексе. Вряд ли кому-то придет идея, что публикация скриншота поискового запроса в качестве ответа на Stack Overflow - это хорошая идея.

Таким образом, я не вижу, как полностью автоматически сгенерированные ответы могут быть полезны в сообществе Stack Overflow² в качестве ответов³. И, соответственно, полностью поддерживаю предложенную политику недопустимости и потенциальных блокировок.

---

Этот ответ является переводом и адаптацией моих ответов на [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384653/383809) и [Academia SE Meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5221/56594).

¹ Чаще всего/в основном это субъективные понятия, однако для данного ответа определение точных границ не имеет значения.

² Я легко могу представить себе другое сообщество, отличное от Stack Overflow на русском (и любого другого сообщества в сети Stack Exchange), где публикация автоматически сгенерированных ответов будет очень полезна. Однако это совсем другой бизнес.

³ Возможно, Stack Exchange сможет интегрировать ChatGPT-подобные механизмы внутрь себя (например, подсказки, когда пользователь задает вопрос), однако это вовсе не о публикации таковых ответов напрямую. И вряд ли вопрос сегодняшнего дня вообще.

Answer (score 13):

К сожалению, пока что ответы ИИ не обладают главным - правильностью. А ввиду своей "наукообразной" формы - вводят в заблуждение и отнимают время на разбор. Пока что ИИ жонглирует словосочетаниями, не понимая их значения. Как пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С интересом будем следить за развитием, может быть года через 2-3 ситуация станет лучше...

Comment: Шикарный пример с пиццами, вполне похоже на логическую цепочку живого не очень эрудированного человека)

Answer (score 9):

- Я так же против халтурных ответов с помощью ИИ. Если наша цель - довести количество ответов на вопросы до 100%, то она стала реально достижима. Но я все-таки думаю, что основная цель этого сообщества в просвещении, в помощи при затруднениях у программиста и в создании базы данных работающих ответов.
- Что показал опыт этих двух недель. Появились «вундеркинды», которые стали быстро набирать очки.  Они не всеми членами сообщества определялись как «пустышки» и за свои полные и развёрнутые ответы получали максимальную поддержку. Но если ответ не попадал в цель или требовал уточнения, то во многих случаях они или ретировались, или начинали «плавать». Я не знаю какая их цель - может за свои баллы получить более высокооплачиваемую работу, или, не дай бог, стать модератором, но их цели точно не совпадают с целями данного сообщества.
- Судя по фактам, хотя они у нас не привели к полному замешательству, как на англоязычном StackOverflow, где не только стали отвечать почти каждый вопрос, а этих «ответов» было несколько!, а  так только слегка возбудили наше сообщество. Но все-таки прослеживается вред который наносит данная практика, как и самому отвечающему, который не разобравшись и не осмысливая проблему выкладывает мгновенное решение, так и задающему, который получает странные ответы, которые похожи на правду.
- Поэтому считаю - принятие ответов ИИ приведёт к быстрой деградации и
  развалу StackOverflow.

Comment: Как вариант - оставлять работающие ответы, если автор явно укажет, откуда он их получил - из GPT, без начисления баллов за них.

Comment: Если GPT вдруг помог - думаю, его ответ можно было бы просто по-человечески дооформить, вылив воду и исправив неточности, что позволит опубликовать его как полноценный ответ

Comment: @andreymal
Я бы не рискнул так делать, максимум на что тянет такой ответ - на комментарий.

Comment: Не думаю, что можно надежно отличить ответ человека, основанный на GPT, от такого же ответа, основанного на статьях-книгах

Comment: @avp
Задайте вопрос  GPT и посмотрите ответ. Сейчас ребята поумнели и слегка корректируют ответы, но изначальная ущербность все равно проявляется.

Comment: @СергейКох, я скорее о том, что 90% ответов тут и сейчас (без всяких GPT) основаны на прочитанном  и не подкрепленном собственным опытом, поэтому их ценность тоже сомнительна

Comment: @avp Да, такое встречалось. Но, как правило, такие ответы не получали большой поддержки. А сейчас замаскированные псевдонаучностью - один такой реальный ответ получил 5 голосов! за день - они выдвигают на передний фланг абсолютно бестолковых ребят, которым вломы даже проверить даденный им свыше код.

Comment: @СергейКох, да это печально. Но скорее всего отражает истинный уровень большинства населения нашей планеты. А GPT только высветило это неравенство

Comment: @avp Да, полностью с вами согласен. Надеюсь только, что мы еще  способны хотя бы замедлить процесс этой деградации.

Comment: @СергейКох на ответы написанные человеком писать комментарии про chatGPT это деградация или просто токсичность?

Answer (score 4):

Я решил попробовать пример Кромстера лично.
Краткий пересказ разговора:

```
- какая пицца более выгодная для покупки?
- 2 мелкие пиццы
- посчитай две площади %детали вопроса%
- %просчитал%
- Просчитав это ты все равно думаешь 
  что 2 мелкие пиццы брать более выгодно?
- Да. Важно понять, что площадь круга не
  имеет ничего общего с размером пиццы и 
  ценой на нее
```

То есть, даже, после наталкивания на правильный ответ ChatGpt НА ДАНУЮ СЕКУНДУ не может ответить правильно на такой простой вопрос. Т.е. ответы ChatGpt не могут считаться коректными ***по причине того что ChatGpt не умеет думать***, а использование таких ответов будут приносить проблемы конечным пользователям ресурса и создавать лишнюю нагрузку на модераторский состав ***и являются в первую очередь вредительскими для ресурса.***

Так же стоит заметить что ***в случае с очень динамически развивающимися языками*** (каким например является swift) ***ChatGpt будет выдавать код который, даже, не будут компилироваться*** в связи с тем, что большинство ответов в интернете написаны на старых версиях языка. То есть выборка для обучения является плохой.

---

Допустимым решением будет:

- Использованием ChatGpt для генерации кода
- С последующими правками кода, что бы он работал как ожидается.

***Но для этого необходимо самому знать как это написать.*** А человек, который и сам знает как написать, практически наверняка не будет так делать. Потому что свой код с нуля написать будет проще чем править сгенерированный код в большинстве случаев.

---

Поэтому за код сгенерированный ChatGPT предлагаю ввести строгий бан на 2 недели времени. При повторных инцидентах на этом же аккаунте удваивать строк наказания. Т.е. 2 недели, месяц, 2 месяца, 4, 8, 16. Но только в случае доказанной виновности.

Comment: Вопрос только в том, кто и как будет собирать доказательства

Comment: @avp да как обычно. модераторы решат, кто виноват.

Comment: @avp неизмененный текст и неизмененный код распознается сервисами на уникальность как на 98-100% неуникальный) Так что доказательства как раз таки не проблема

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_AGRESSION_IN_UA, вот будет интересная коллизия, если GPT в качестве решения выдаст код, взятый из SO (например, ваш)

Comment: @avp да если честно как-то пофиг) На самом деле тот бекендный код который я пишу на своих проектах и тот который выкладываню на SO разительно отличаются практически всегда. Т.к. решения которые я применяю внутри своих проектов более нетривиальны и ближе к функциональному программированию. То есть в том подходе, который SOшники не используют или практически не используют. Кроме того часто опираются на какие-то штуки личного пользования вроде собственной системы сигналов, написание кода на Result-ах и многопоточных аналогах резалтов.

Comment: В общем, все самое-самое ценное на самом деле идет в личном пользовании т.к. большинство пользователей SO в этом все равно не разберутся или просто на просто не поймут всей прелести этих решений) Пусть бездумно копируют мой код в общем доступе пропуская его через chatGPT. Пусть падает качество среднего программиста - я стану от этого только более ценным спецом.

Comment: @Andrew_STOP_RU_AGRESSION_IN_UA, да, я тоже считаю, что настоящее мастерство всегда скрывается от глаз общества. Иногда о нем говорят, но часто это пересказы людей, которые не до конца осознают все тонкие моменты

Answer (score 3):

У "Искуственного Интеллекта", по крайней мере на сегодняшний день, есть одна большая проблема: **оно не умеет в думать**, что является одной из основополагающей программирования, а просто берёт код из базы знаний. Алгоритмические задачки после правки - вполне (т.к по сути берёт уже существующий код на котором тренилась ИИ), а затем подобные ответы можно постить, я считаю это приемлимым, но это читерство как по мне, однако это решает поставленный вопрос, что как раз таки и является смыслом stackoverflow. У этого само собой есть и минусы, об этом уже написал в ответе @Сергей Кох.

Отсутствие мышления делает её не интеллектом, а всего лишь повторялкой по наработанной базе и отличным помощником "подай-принеси-идинафиг-небеси".

Ну и вот пример, чтобы не быть пустословным, недавно я попросил спроектировать структуру Money на C# и вот, что GPTChat мне выдал:

```
struct Money 
{
   public int Dollars { get; set; }
   public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Это прекрасно показывает, что ИИ просто не понимает, что пишет.

Я в целом ЗА ИИ, если вопрос подразумевает длинный и сложный ответ, и при этом ответчик сам знает ответ, и сможет корректировать длинный ответ ИИ.

Я недавно спрашивал так же очень тонкие детали по C# и в целом платформе .NET, ИИ с ответами справлялась, хоть и надо было её "подтолкнуть" в правильное русло, при этом ответ был довольно объемный, это попросту сэкономит время как ответчику, так и тому, кто задаёт вопрос (т.к очевидно ответ хочется получить прямо здесь и сейчас, а не ждать, пока ответчик соберёт все знания и ссылки в пост).

Comment: Как будто ответ GPT писала, а не живой человек ))))) .. оно не умеет в думать, что является одной из основополагающей **?** программирования, а **?** просто берёт код **?** из базы знаний. Алгоритмические задачки после правки **?** - вполне (т.к по сути берёт уже существующий код на котором тренилась ИИ), а затем **?** подобные ответы можно постить, я считаю это приемлимым, но это читерство **?** как по мне, однако это решает поставленный **?** вопрос, что как раз таки и является смыслом **?** stackoverflow

Comment: *"ответ был довольно объемный, это попросту сэкономит время как ответчику, так и тому, кто задаёт вопрос"* - считать объемность ответа мерилом качества ... ну такое себе ..

Comment: @Kromster я этого не говорил и вы вырвали из контекста часть предложения. Если вопрос будет типа "каковы функции аллокатора и коллектора, кто их запускает и кто ими управляет" - качественный ответ не будет состоять из парочки пунктов "ну там среда запускает она управляет она там выделяет память ну выпоняли)". ИИ сейчас - бездумная машина которая отвечает тем, на чем тренилась, а не так, как правильно. Однако это не исключает вероятность правильного ответа ЕСЛИ ответ ИИ будет редактировать человек который хорошо разбирается в теме.

Comment: @Kromster ну а по поводу текста моего вопроса - да, выразился я мягко говоря кривовато для человека

Comment: *"Если вопрос будет типа "каковы функции аллокатора и коллектора, кто их запускает и кто ими управляет""* - то имхо гораздо проще будет скопировать соответствующую главу из какого-нибудь учебника. Сила человека (востребованная на SO), имхо, в том чтобы упрощать (т.е. давать более четкие и емкие) ответы на сложные вопросы, а не расплываться длинными мутными ответами (как ИИ сейчас).

Comment: @Kromster ну тут вы правы абсолютно, но я думаю через некоторое время будет не какой-нибудь ChatGPT, а какой-нибудь GoogleAI который будет давать нормальные ответы без воды, дело только лишь в том, как натренить и чем натренить) Дело времени

Comment: Вот на БазеЗнаний StackOverflow (человеко-наполняемой, де-дублицированной, без домашек и "сделайте за меня") и тренить ;-) А самоиндуцирующую обратную связь (когда ИИ тренится на ответах данных ИИ) - запретить :-)

Comment: @Kalmankantaja впервые слышу про GoogleAI, если даже он будет давать ответы (не уверен, что нормальные), то они скорее всего всё равно будут основываться на наборе текста GPT3+, либо эти ответы будут прямиком из GPT3+.

Comment: @ΝNL993 да это так, отсебятина) Просто название которое первое в голове появилось)

Answer (score 3):

Я тоже против использования ИИ для публикации ответов на ruSO.

Вы задумывались, как работает ИИ под капотом? Он же не сам код пишет. По сути дела, ИИ работает как поисковик — он ищет примеры кода в  интернете, и с помощью сложных алгоритмов из множества кусков кода и статьей собирает код, дополняет код пояснениями, предугадывая каждое следующее слово.

Казалось бы, что такого? Вроде отвечающие на SO так же делают, собирают информацию из разных источников, анализируют её. **НО у ИИ есть несколько проблем!**

1. Выше сказали: он не умеет думать и не умеет оценивать правильность информации, и может при объяснении неверное словечко подставить, тем самым меняя смысл всей фразы и даже всего ответа. Он жонглирует словами.
2. Никто про это выше почему-то не сказал: а вы не думаете, что ИИ может просто **украсть**, **сплагиатить** кусок чужого кода, чужого ответа (например, с того же самого SO)? Более того, он так иногда и делает! Доказательство тому - [этот ответ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421832/21103898).

В общем chatGPT спросили: почему на StackOverFlow пользователи, генерирующие ответы chatGPT, должны быть забанены? Вот ответ:

> Stack Overflow — это веб-сайт, на котором программисты и разработчики могут задавать вопросы, связанные с кодированием и компьютерным программированием, и отвечать на них. Он предназначен для людей, которым нужна помощь в решении конкретных проблем программирования или которые хотят узнать больше по определенной теме. Поскольку ответы, сгенерированные ИИ, не всегда могут быть точными или актуальными, они потенциально могут вызвать путаницу или ввести в заблуждение пользователей, которые ищут помощь в Stack Overflow. Кроме того, ответы, сгенерированные ИИ, могут не всегда соответствовать правилам форматирования и стиля сайта, что может затруднить их чтение или понимание. По этим причинам для Stack Overflow может быть уместно запретить ответы, сгенерированные ИИ.

Угадайте, откуда машинка взяла эту информацию? Если не из того же поста, то явно откуда-то из сети, возможно с MSE. **Но это ещё не всё!** Дальше  вопрос был задан *немного по-другому* ("Почему такие ответы должны быть разрешены?") и получил совершенно противоположенный ответ: да, такие ответы должны быть разрешены....

> Есть несколько потенциальных преимуществ разрешения ответов, сгенерированных ИИ, на Stack Overflow. Во-первых, ответы, сгенерированные ИИ, потенциально могут дать более точные и подробные ответы на вопросы пользователей. Это может быть особенно полезно для сложных технических вопросов, на которые специалистам может быть трудно ответить. Кроме того, ответы, генерируемые ИИ, могут помочь снизить нагрузку на специалистов-людей, позволяя им сосредоточиться на более важных задачах.

Второй ответ наверняка тоже не моделька выдумала, собрала по кусочкам из сети или с MSE (есть пользователи, которые говорят, что ИИ-ответы это нормально).

Вопрос был снова переформулирован, и третий ответ был такой:

> Тем не менее, есть также некоторые потенциальные недостатки, которые следует учитывать. Например, ответы, сгенерированные ИИ, не всегда могут быть точными или полезными, и могут быть опасения по поводу возможности предвзятости в алгоритмах, используемых для генерации ответов. Кроме того, у некоторых пользователей могут возникнуть опасения по поводу использования ИИ в целом, и они могут предпочесть получить ответы от экспертов-людей.
> В целом, разрешить или нет сгенерированные ИИ ответы на Stack Overflow — сложное решение, которое должно быть тщательно рассмотрено сообществом.

Это насчёт авторских прав и правильности ответов.

Comment: Тут не все так просто, система машинного обучения использует чужие тексты, но не напрямую. Подобно тому, как человек использует информацию из учебника математики при каждом расчете, не ссылаясь на него, но плагиатом это не считается. Это не то чтобы полностью исключает вопросы к создателям ChatGPT (к юрлицам с конскими бюджетами их всегда больше, чем к физлицам). Но, чтобы обосновать обвинение в плагиате, придется серьезно потрудится.