# Участник опубликовал 22 ответа за 70 минут. Не сгенерировал ли он их с помощью ChatGPT?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, нормы-поведения, генеративный-ии

На мой вопрос дал ответ один [пользователь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/540296/andrei-popruha). Дело в том, что зарегистрировался он сегодня и [дал 22 ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/540296/andrei-popruha?tab=answers)(!!!) за 70 минут:

| Ответ | Время публикации |
| --- | --- |
| [Первый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1491546) | 2023-01-31 06:17:33Z |
| [Последний](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1491581) (удалён модератором) | 2023-01-31 07:27:02Z |

Выглядят эти ответы нормально. Не все они сильно развёрнутые, но поражает их количество. К тому же ответы про разные языки программирования: про [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [с#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%23), [kotlin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) и [powershell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell)! Некоторые ответы на "продвинутые" темы. Не сгенерированы ли эти ответы с помощью *ChatGPT*?

Comment: Неплохо было бы (это уже оращение к модератором) связаться с user:540296 и спросить его каким способом он так быстро закинул свои ответы на ruSO

Comment: @avp может он три года готовился? А то некоторых ведь удивляют самоответы, данные в ту же секунду, что и вопрос опубликован :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну, три не три... Я посмотрел на эти ответы. Такое впечатление, что они скопированы из сети. Однако, на некоторые комментарии к ответам автор откликнулся и осмысленно их поредактировал. Так что на нейросеть (или я сильно отстал от жизни и пора приписать им разум?) не похоже

Comment: @avp ЧТО именно не похоже на нейросеть? Речь всё же не о полномасштабном боте на SO, как я понимаю, а о человеке, который копипастит ответы из ChatGPT.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, сам участник. Про источник копипасты ничего не могу сказать. А что мы вообще должны делать если  куски правильных ответов из ChatGPT являются копипастой из SO (или википедии)?

Comment: @avp с википедии нельзя, насколько я помню по описанию меток. С SO надо ссылку давать на первоисточник.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, хотите сказать, что тут все теперь должны заняться отыскиванием запрещенной копипасты в ответах и их удалением? Может будем реалистами и примем новую реальность? Источник авторства не важен (соответственно и ссылка на него не обязательна). Если ответ правильный, то тут ему место, если ответ не правильный, то он должен быть заминусован.

Comment: @avp новая реальность уже [обозначена тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12247/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, суть этого топика -- `"К сожалению, сгенерированные тексты в основном оказываются не верны."`. Насчет неверных ответов я уже сказал. Тут разговор, надеюсь, вы понимаете, пошел о несколько другом. О важности авторства первоначального текста и обязательности ссылок на источник для признания легитимности текста ответа. (я предлагаю признавать ответ легитимным только на основании его правильности. Остальные требования можно отбросить)

Comment: Симпатизирую на самом деле позиции @avp, но это все _дизраптит_ систему доверия высокореповым участникам, да и смысл существования SO, в конченом счете. Возможно, StackExchange стоит подумать не о том как бороться с ChatGPT, а том как интегрировать к себе новые возможности. Пока кто-то другой не сделал сайт "СпросиИИ.ком", где ответы дают моментально, а одноразовые аккаунты с домашками никто не шеймит.

Comment: @ 
avp Источник авторства важен. Нельзя выдавать чужой труд за свой.  Использование ChatGPT недопустимо на StackOverFlow, это уже давно решено тут: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-gpt-%d0%b8-chatgpt-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0

Comment: @ avp Поскольку Использование ChatGPT для генерации ответов на StackOverFlow запрещено, то пользователи, делающие это, должны получить предупреждение, бан на некоторое время или даже лишиться аккаунта.

Comment: Вот еще один кандидат на проверку - тревогал его ответы - сейчас он заблокирован, но скоро разблокируется - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/533449 (мб какие-то ранние ответы и потерли уже - там ChatGPT прям сквозил тоже)

Comment: @Зонтик, когда вы даете ответ на вопрос, то пишете текст, используя сведения, полученные вами из других текстов. Если в  качестве источника вы используете, например, не учебники, а статьи в интернете, найденные через гугл, то это нормально?  Если да, то каким образом вы можете гарантировать, что используемая вами статья не основана на тексте, выданном ChatGPT и кем-то творчески отредактированном? Очевидно, что никак не можете. Идея понятна?

Comment: На самом деле не вижу проблемы если человек взял за основу своего поста ответ от ИИ (при условии если ответ предварительно проверен на работоспособность и исправлены присущие автогенеренному тексту огрехи). Правда наверное было бы честно по отношению к другим пользователям указывать что ответ основан на ИИ или вообще делать отметку в профиле "Использую ИИ, не являюсь экспертом в той или иной области"

Comment: ChatGPT можно попросить проверить его ли это текст?

Comment: @Зонтик, если между @ и именем пользователя пробел - обращение не работает, участник не получит оповещение.

Comment: @avp Посмотрите ответ пользователя Kromster . Этот участник просто копирует информацию из chatgpt

Comment: @yolosora Посмотрите ответ пользователя Kromster . Этот участник просто копирует информацию из chatgpt.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy просто задать такой же вопрос в такой же формулировке =).

Comment: Удивлен пассивностью модераторов. Надо было сразу снести ответы, а автора - в бан. [В правилах уже есть явный запрет на ChatGPT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: @Зонтик, с вашим конкретным пользователем всем уже давно все ясно (расстрелять (в смысле, забанить)). Речь пошла уже о более глубоких материях

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, вчера слышал по радио дискуссию о ChatGPT. Есть специальный сервис, который пытается определить, является ли текст творением этой нейросети. К сожалению, процент распознавания около 25

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, нашел вот такой https://writer.com/ai-content-detector/ детектор. Попробовал на нескольких своих ответах. Оказывается, я человек с вероятностью от 39 до 80%

Comment: @avp Проще копировать подозрительные вопросы в ChatGPT. Тогда  вероятность распознавания - около 90% =).  ChatGPT будет давать похожие ответы, и всё будет ясно =). Возможно, так можно вообще  искоренить ChatGPT на StackOverFlow. А все эти детекторы не очень точны.

Comment: @Зонтик не то чтобы проще. 90% времени ChatGPT перегружен и в него не залогиниться.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не вижу по вашей ссылке ничего про бан и удаление ответов.

Comment: @Nofate эмм.. а вы точно все прочли, с заголовком? *"публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима"* - это ли не явный запрет? И не многократное ли нарушение запретов приводит в предупреждениям и в последствии к банам?

Comment: @Kromster автор получил предупреждение в связи с _подозрением_ на использование ИИ. Нового контента с тех пор он не постил. В прошлых случаях я удалял посты, когда можно было однозначно доказать gpt. Сейчас ситуация несколько иная. На пресловутый вопрос про serialVersionUID дан вполне адекватный ответ, скажем.

Comment: @Nofate с таким пояснением согласен, спасибо!

Comment: если ответ рабочий, то это же хорошо, что проблема быстро решилась) а если там просто набор слов, то ну такое...

Comment: а в чём суть претензий? Плохие или непонятные ответы? Ответил? Хорошо.

Comment: Ещё один ["скорострел"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/436000/web-developer?tab=answers&sort=newest) - интервал ≈4 мин. Что-то много суперподготовленных в последнее время.

Comment: @Nofate ещё один "гений". Даже не скрывает https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1497005/292793

Comment: @сакура *"а в чём суть претензий?"* --- наверное основная проблема  в том, что часто ответы от chatGPT это набор не связанных предложений и код, который и на вопрос-то толком не отвечает и вроде код есть и даже работает, но по логике совершенно бессмысленный.  То есть выглядит на первый взгляд разумно, но профи поймёт что это бессвязная белеберда. В итоге новичок, который задавал вопрос или придёт с инета радостно скопирует код и вставит себе. А толку ноль....То есть вкратце - представленная информация - дезинформация, которую новичок не сможет различить от подлинной, научится плохому

Answer (score 15):

Поспрашивал сейчас ChatGPT и ответы действительно сильно похожи на то что постил участник.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Беда еще и в том, что сами ответы от раза к разу разные и каждый раз чуть-чуть иные по сути. Т.е. **у ChatGPT отлично получается лепить подходящие слова вместе**, но каждый раз это рулетка - слепится ли что-то по сути правильное или нет.

Comment: Я бы сказал даже - неприлично похожи, а не сильно :) тут действительно - с поличным.

Comment: Можно ли считать этот факт доказательством, что участник использовал chatGPT? А если можно, то как пресечь публикацию дальнейших ответов с помощью chatGPT?

Comment: @Зонтик можно "пресечь" публикацию ответов от этого участника, глобально - скорее всего нет. Наверное можно ограничить количество ответов в час, но это полумера, конечно.

Comment: @insolor
Я имел в виду конкретно этого участника.  На самом деле в глобальном плане сделать это не так уж и трудно: просто находить таких участников (как выяснилось это сделать легко=)). И залить "подозрительные" ответы в chatGPT.

Comment: @Зонтик конкретного участника - очень легко, решается баном (временным или постоянным при повторных нарушениях). Для глобального решения уже нужна какая-то эвристика. Когда участник дает много ответов в короткий промежуток времени - тут да, очень подозрительно. Но точно так же можно было постить все ответы постепенно, в течение недели, например, и заподозрить что-то было бы уже сложнее. Не будешь же каждый вопрос-ответ на сайте через ChatGPT прогонять, и сравнивать - похоже или не похоже.

Comment: если у вас есть аккаунт, уже [можно проверить](https://www.axios.com/2023/01/31/openai-chatgpt-detector-tool-machine-written-text) был ли текст написан AI

Comment: @insolor Может быть, когда-нибудь для поиска подозрительных ответов на `StackOverFlow` какого-нибудь бота добавят =). Ну или это будет делать `дух сообщества`,  отправляя модератором ссылки на ответы, которые могут быть сгенерированы chatGPT.

Comment: @Зонтик "бот какой-нибудь" - это [deus ex machina](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3_%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B), не объяснение как это в принципе это глобально решить, а введение в обсуждение какого-то "черного ящика", который как-то сам должен понимать, что ответ сгенерирован нейронкой.

Comment: @Зонтик очевидно, что это будет какой-то бот. Но как именно внутри его реализовать - совсем не очевидно. Предложение использовать openai - вариант, но он определяет вероятностно. Прогонять каждый вопрос через chatgpt - вариант. Но в целом и то и другое - требует машинных ресурсов.

Answer (score 14):

Думаю, тут нужно копнуть чуть глубже:

Одна из глобальных целей сообщества - получить большую и доступную базу вопросов/ответов, которые будут **одобрены** **участниками** сообщества в своей правильности и эффективности.

И основная задумка заключается в том, что сообщество управляется **людьми**, которые  объективны в своих оценках (ну, почти всегда), и, если даётся ответ (без учёта его происхождения), который отвечает на заданный вопрос и не является низкокачественным, то чем это плохо?

Он вполне имеет право находиться на сайте и получать плюсы, раз действительно представляет из себя ценность.

Другой вопрос в том, что несмотря на то, что ChatGPT действительно многого достиг - он пока ещё практически **не способен** давать действительно качественные ответы, раскрывающие суть, а иногда и вовсе - пишет то, что откровенно неверно.

**P.S** Если вдруг кто-то меня неправильно понял - я все-таки **против** ИИшных ответов, если они **явно** такие, и сильно отличаются от человеческих (водянистые/совсем не туда), но, если разница незаметна, а ответ хороший, то не вижу глобальной катастрофы.

Поглядев ответы данного участника могу согласиться с тем, что наиболее вероятно использование ChatGPT, именно по тому, как построены и размазаны ответы.

И да, объективно - хотя в них и можно найти решение проблемы - бОльшая часть из них довольно низкокачественная.

Тем не менее, это реальность, с которой в ближайшее время придётся что-то делать, такие ситуации явно будут повторяться, поэтому предлагаю такие варианты:

- Если  ответ является низкокачественным и его содержимое намекает на то, что оно было сгенерировано - не следует ставить ему положительные оценки, даже, возможно, наоборот, следует поставить отрицательную, и написать свой ответ, который будет более точным, тем самым сообщество пополнится ещё одним хорошим **человеческим** ответом.
- Люди, которые злоупотребляют использованием ИИ для ответов и не стремятся к тому, чтобы сделать его человекочитаемым должны получать предупреждение, с возможной блокировкой в будущем, потому что такие участники вредят сообществу.

Comment: Хорошо бы привлечь модераторов к этому делу, ведь только модераторы могут посылать предупреждения...

Comment: @Зонтик это в целом доступно при помощи тревог - отправляете на сообщение и указываете причину

Answer (score 13):

Т.к. модераторы достаточно пассивны в текущем наборе на ruSO, я предлагаю на подобные посты, которые вызывают подозрение в использовании chatGPT, вешать тревогу типа "спам".

> [image: спам ли]

Если таких тревог набирается на сообщении несколько - в силу вступает автоматическое удаление поста и уменьшение репутации автора на 100 поинтов за каждое такое сообщение. Если подтверждения "спамности" от других не поступает - спам тревоги автоматически же откатываются.

Таким образом, и волки сыты (участники не видят всякий gpt шлак), и овцы целы (никто не гнобит модераторов за бездействие, хотя стоило бы).

Comment: Это конкретно работающее предложение. Сколько нам нужно плюсиков на этом ответе, чтобы он был признан сообществом как руководство к действию?

Comment: А точно участник блокируется? Мне кажется это ручное действие модератора.

Comment: @insolor снимается репутация у спаммера. Блокировки автоматической нет, я ошибся.

Comment: Я против использования функционала не по назначению. Рекламой подобные посты уж никак не являются.

Comment: @Kromster откуда такая уверенность? владельцы ChatGPT предлагают свои услуги за деньги. Это вполне может быть скрытой рекламой - "смотрите какой крутой ИИ, даже живые люди не распознают подвоха и плюсуют".

Comment: Мне ChatGPT предложился бесплатно. Хотите расшевелить модераторов - давайте флагать "Требуется вмешательство модератора" со словами "ChatGPT". Если не будут реагировать, то raise жалобы до SE, что модераторы не справляются.

Comment: @Kromster "raise жалобы до SE" вот сейчас было очень смешно, честно.

Comment: на словах "жалобы до SE" действительно весь взоржал.

Comment: Не понимаю, что именно вам показалось смешным, что до этого не дойдет, или что вы не сможете составить кейс который там не заигнорят?

Comment: проблемы индейцев шерифа не волнуют, @Kromster. Только вот причём тут МОЙ кейс?

Comment: Мне кажутся, что лучше вешать тревогу не "спам" (она скорее всего будет отклонена), а "требует вмешательства модератора" , с пометкой "это похоже на chatgpt". Я уже сделал так с ответом на мой вопрос и кинул ссылку на ответ @Kromster

Comment: @Kromster лично мне показалась забавной ваша вера в то, что SE что-то будет делать. Я несколько раз писал администрации, ответ получил только один раз.

Comment: Отмена участника за всего лишь "подозрения" - омерзительно

Comment: @Эникейщик вне контекста сложно сказать, но если ruSO окажется заполонен ChatGPT и спамом, то делать что-то будут. А если 1-2 спамера в неделю и 1-2 ИИвода, вычищаемых силами модераторов и сообщества - то реагировать как-бы и не на что.

Comment: @Kromster на счёт вычищения модераторами вот такой [коммент](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12327/%d0%a3%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-22-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-70-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-c#comment53425_12327) есть: *"не вижу по вашей ссылке ничего про бан и удаление ответов"*

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а зачем вы это мне пишете? Есть прямой запрет. Если модератор его не "догоняет", то надо ему напомнить - присоединяйтесь.

Comment: @Kromster ну как зачем? Чтобы быть в курсе. Да и в продолжении темы эскалации жалоб и т.п.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ то что мы тут с вами посмеиваемся над модерацией совершенно бестолково. Ну да, решим мы что все плохо, допустим взоржем, дальше жаловаться друг другу будем? Если есть предметная жалоба, то надо пилить пост, подтягивать пруфы.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ лучше не ломайте механизмы, а кидайте тревогу "не является ответом", если там действительно плохое качество ответа или откровенная рандомная ахинея.

Comment: Хм. Вот сейчас некий пользователь тоже решил сломать механизмы и отметил как "Спам" этот ответ.

Comment: @Nofate я бы мог так делать, но для этого надо, чтобы модераторы активнее себя вели. Поэтому вариант со спамом мне кажется более действенным. Ну и опять-таки, почему это не может быть спамом (скрытой рекламой)? Мне кажется, что вполне может.

Comment: Это не может быть рекламой, потому что нет прямой ссылки или хоть какого-то упоминания рекламируемого продукта. Все остальное будет домыслами.

Comment: @Nofate Кидать тревогу "не является ответом" на такие сообщения - и есть сломать механизм работы тревог. Ведь  **"не следует использовать сигнал тревоги, чтобы указать на неточность или неверность ответа"**. Не является ответом - это когда то, что опубликовано как ответ является комментарием. Я уже писал, что в таких случаях нужно ставить тревогу "требует вмешательства модератора", и написать "chatGPT".

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1491697/373567 (удалён модератором) - модераторы реагируют на тревоги, вот например я флагнул явный ChatGPT, описал кратко свои подозрения. Тревога помечена как полезная, ответ удалён.

Answer (score 3):

Тоже стал встречать ответы, которые скорее всего сгенерированы ИИ. Далеко ходить не надо, вот в конкурсном: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1492796/361482
Задаешь такой же вопрос нейросети - получаешь похожий ответ, без конкретики и прочих уточнений. А потом "Не работает? Да и ладно, я пытался, тогда не знаю как"))

Answer (score -5):

Может они пытаются заставить чат-бота проходить тест Тьюринга? Типа как долго оно может продержаться среди людей прежде чем будет вычислено.

Comment: «Я не боюсь машину, которая пройдёт тест Тьюринга. Я боюсь машину, которая намеренно его завалит»

Comment: Одна из возможных схем использования ИИ, когда его полноценно доделают или если это уже есть, то это сокрытие его для получения контроля над всем и вся.