# Что делать с бессмысленными вопросами?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Например, возьмём такой вопрос:

Заголовок:

> Пустотааааааааааааааааа

Тело:

> Здесь ничего нет
> Совсем ничего.
> Мяу

*Примечание - такой вопрос действительно [был задан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1493233/176217) 05.02.2023*
(ссылка доступна для участников с [привилегией просмотра удалённых сообщений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools))

---

Что с ним делать?

1. Ставим минус
2. Просто минус выглядит недостаточно, ставим тревогу.

   Из причин тревоги по смыслу больше всего подходит "спам",
   но меня смутило его описание:

   > Рекламирует продукт или услугу, не раскрывая при этом причастность автора.

   тут явно про что-то другое.

Итак, вопрос - **Какую тревогу ставить на бессмысленные вопросы?**

Comment: Я бы поставил `необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством`

Comment: Ну а вообще встроена [система автоудаления бесполезных вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).

Comment: Ставьте тревогу, модераторы когда-нибудь удалят.

Comment: @Nofate, у меня и возник вопрос, *какую* тревогу ставить.

Comment: В самом деле мусор? Или выражение мнения об уровне участников этого сайта?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для начала, поставить голос "против".

Далее. Если ещё нет привилегии закрывать вопросы, то ставьте тревогу "Необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством" или "Необходимо улучшить - Непонятна суть вопроса".

Если функционал закрытия доступен, то сразу "Непонятна суть вопроса".

Далее такой вопрос улетает в очередь проверок, где с ним разберутся так, как он того заслуживает. Скорее всего, он будет удалён, если не превратится во что-то действительно осмысленное.

Ставить тревогу для модератора в данном случае не считаю строго необходимым. Мусора всегда будет полно, но избавиться от него можно и без модераторов.

Answer (score 1):

Тревога -> Спам.

Собираем 6 штук и автор отправляется в бан с вычитанием сотни репутации.

Comment: Но ведь так нельзя. @nofate против. Да и откуда бан?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, не вижу я, где он против. Его ответов тут нет. Ну не совсем бан, а запрет на публикацию, в том числе на сутки для ip.

Comment: Так я [покажу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12327/%d0%a3%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-22-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-70-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-c#comment53439_12331)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну chatgpt вроде по другой схеме?

Comment: Что ты в это вкладываешь? Как я понял его подход - ни в коем случае нельзя использовать тревоги "спам" на том, что спамом не является. Другое дело, что понятие "спам" у всех может быть разное.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ не совсем. Тревога "Спам" это сильнодействующий механизм для однозначно деструктивного контента (то есть не вызывающего вопросов). В случае с "азаза111" вопросов нет.

Comment: @Nofate деструктивный контент - это когда фейк выдают за правду (например, потому что GPTChat так решил). Когда сразу видно мусор - это не деструктивный контент, он не ставит собой целью обмануть сознание читателя.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вроде мы тут не про ChatGPT.

Comment: @Nofate именно! Поэтому "азаза111" не так опасен. Т.е. почему ты считаешь, что его как "спам" бомбить можно, а ChatGPT - нет, для меня загадка.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ если вы можете формально доказать, что ответ сгенерирован ChatGPT (и представлен в исходном виде) - используйте "Спам". Я не могу (в актуальной версии).

Comment: Так-то я тут не создаю правила. Каждый использует тревоги, как он считает адекватно ситуации. 
Вы ворчите, я ворчу )