# Переименовать тревогу "спам" в "реклама"

Tags: предложение, тревоги, спам

Предлагаю переименовать тревогу `спам` в `реклама`, т. к. по-моему это слово однозначнее показывает назначение тревоги.

Особенно это видно по описанию:

> **Рекламирует** продукт или услугу, не раскрывая при этом причастность автора.

- речь идёт явно про рекламу.

О том же говорит описание метки [спам](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc):

> Вопросы о нежелательной **рекламе** в вопросах, ответах и комментариях на StackOverflow на русском.

Правда, если моё предложение примут, придётся кое-что ещё переделать - переименовать метку [спам](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc), да и в справке используется тот же термин `спам`.

Answer (score 8):

В целом в сети Stack Exchange спам - [это скорее реклама](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/383809). Однако важно отметить, что сайты сообществ могут разработать свою трактовку флага спам. Например, [на Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345333/2452869) белиберду (*gibberish*) не возбраняется отмечать как спам.

В русскоязычном Stack Overflow [есть обсуждение тревоги Спам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7326/337980), которая в основном о рекламе, однако я не нашел однозначно "узкой" трактовки (также как и "широкой"). Возможно, стоит это обсудить.

Также стоит упомянуть [предложение переименовать spam в advertisement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58433/383809) на общей Мете, которое не было поддержано.

Итак, по моему мнению:

1. Переименование в ***рекламу*** ничего не улучшит, и даже несколько затруднит: можно начать спорить о том, что есть реклама, а что нет, тогда как ***спам*** — более всеобъемлющее понятие.
2. Одной из возможных мотиваций к перемименованию может являться злоупотребление тревогой спам и\или конфликт модераторов и сообщества по трактовке. Такового я тоже не наблюдаю.
3. С точки зрения составления "правил", по многим вопросам стоит давать общие указания, вместо частных, чтобы оставалась свобода действий ответственных людей (у тех, кто ставит флаги, кто их обрабатывает, и у автоматики). На мой взгляд это как раз такой случай ([intentionalism vs textualism если интересно](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/legal-interpretation/#TheoLegaInte)).

Следовательно, я против переименования.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение, понял, что не надо переименовывать. Но, возник следующий вопрос: если название тревоги должно остаться "спам", то может быть надо дополнить *описание* этой тревоги, т. к. сейчас там исключительно про рекламу (из-за чего собственно я и предложил её переименовать)?

Comment: @wchistow возможно. Однако (в отличие от приведенной ссылки на Meta Stack Overflow) я не нахожу дискуссии подтверждающей официальное расширенное толкование.

Answer (score -1):

Спам - это не только реклама. Всякую ерунду, вроде:

```
Пустотааааааааааааааааа
Здесь ничего нет
Совсем ничего.
Мяу
```

[тоже тревогают как спам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12348/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8/12350#12350) (см. ответ `@Qwertiy`). Спамом может быть большое количество комментариев вроде "АААААА". Да и вообще "спам" - понятие очень обширное, поэтому ничего переименовывать не надо.

Единственное, что можно сделать (но не факт что нужно) - немного поправить описание тревоги, а то из-за этого на данный момент спам почему-то трактуется некоторыми участниками только как "реклама". Я бы добавил такое описание тревоги "спам":

> Это сообщение содержит рекламу продукта, услуги **или бессмыслицу**.