# Вопросы про не работающий код от GPT - что делать?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, генеративный-ии

Сейчас стали появляться вопросы такого вида:

> Попросил GPT написать, но что-то не работает <...>

(пример - [Bot для поиска и пересылки сообщений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1516904))

Понятно, что это плохой вопрос. Но вот что с такими вопросами конкретно делать? Какую тревогу ставить?

Comment: @NNL вопрос не в том как их закрыть, а что с ними делать

Comment: @Kromster тогда наверное стоит и у другого [подобного вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12348/) убрать эту метку?

Comment: @ΝNL993 не уверен. Там очевидно, что если вопрос бессмысленнен, то его хочется удалить. Здесь же ситуация может быть чуть тоньше. Если ТС или модератор вернет метку - трогать не буду.

Comment: Вот ещё пример такого вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1517315/

Comment: Как за просьбы выполнить домашку :) Это же не человек сам трудился... Как за предельно глупые вопросы приходится ставить "вызван опечаткой"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> .. но *что-то не работает*

По сути это аналогично *"нашел код в Сети, попросил Имярека написать мне программу и т.п., а она не работает"*.

В большинстве случаев будет достаточно стандартной тревоги:

> Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Ну и конечно вы можете поставить вопросу минус, если вам кажется что:

> Вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; он непонятен или не несёт пользы

Comment: Не сказал бы, что аналогично. Логика человека непредсказуема, а ChatGPT работает по определённым правилам.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ мне кажется, у ChatGPT есть определенные паттерны в работе, но в целом они принципиально не отличаются от обобщенного  "Имярека".

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, что подобные вопросы можно интерпретировать точно так же, как ошибки работы в любом стороннем продукте. То есть в первую очередь это надо переадресовывать в службу поддержки продукта. Если же есть какой-то работающий обходной путь, то, имхо, вполне можно опубликовать такое решение на SO. Конечно, если это решение не сгенерировано самим ChatGPT :)

Comment: *"переадресовывать в службу поддержки продукта"* кажется бесполезным, т.к. ChatGPT это языковая модель (T9 на стероидах), а не какой-нибудь условный Code Complete. (З.Ы. минус не ставил)

Comment: @Kromster тем не менее, должно быть можно предложить более или менее подходящие запросы, которые с разной вероятностью будут давать подходящие ответы. Это инструмент, который можно использовать по-разному.

Comment: Сложно сказать.. *"ChatGPT, please write me a С++ function to repair carburetor with a fork"* выдает код. Как его не переспрашивай, но заработать он, например, принципиально не сможет )