# Что это за "ChatGPT"-маркировку модератор поместил на ответ?

Tags: обсуждение, модераторский-произвол, генеративный-ии

Листал посты на закрытие и увидел *прекрасную* шапку на ответе добавленную правкой за авторством модератора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1509445/2

Как видно, время он выбрал тоже весьма своеобразное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос - что это за форма маркировки, он её сам придумал или это новый стандарт? Где это обсуждалось, какие действия предполагает? Или он это на все ответы будет лепить по своему разумению? Или это неудачная первоапрельская выходка?

---

Ждем обещанного ответа Qwertiy уже больше недели )

---

Прошло 2 недели, ответа от Qwertiy нету. Ответ HolyBlackCat получил поддержку +12/-2. Плашки убрал. При необходимости, прошу Qwertiy создать новый вопрос/обсуждение о необходимости и оформлении таких плашек.

Comment: Главное, успеть в первую минуту первого апреля по UTC.

Comment: Да и в целом сейчас не понятно, как контролировать запрет на использование ChatGPT. Поймать за руку практически невозможно

Comment: На всех ответах этого участника подобная плашка. (Ответы, кстати, и правда похожи на сгенерированные ChatGPT)

Comment: [8 неудалённых](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD+%D1%81+%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC+ChatGPT%22) и [10 удалённых (mod link)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD+%D1%81+%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC+ChatGPT%22+deleted%3A1). Попозже отвечу. А на 1 апреля было [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1509974/178988).

Comment: Кстати, хороший способ. Ведь на разных ответах написано разное: где-то "код может приводить к багам", где-то "код хороший, но описание неверноре", где-то "верность ответа не проверялась"

Comment: Плохой способ, т.к. это по сути на каждый пятый ответ лепить можно (и даже не важно GPT он или нет), замусоривая все плашками.

Comment: @Kromster а что вы предлагаете? Можно. конечно удалять gpt-ответы, но так есть риск, что что-нибудь не то удалим.

Comment: Время конечно впечатляет...

Comment: @Зонтик я пока не предлагаю, я интересуюсь что это за самодеятельность

Comment: вот поэтому и нужны переодические выборы, потому что когда человек понимает, что может делать что хочет и у него есть некая "власть", редко когда он остается адекватным и соблюдает изначальные правила,,,,,хотелось бы посмотреть на лицо данного юзера/админа/человека если он обнаружит такое поведение/отсебятину/самоРешение/самодеятельность от только что зарегестрированного пользователя....ахаха, он его просто забанит))) @Kromster а вот если бы Ваша анкета была дополнена и не было этой фразы=не планирую...которую все подметили, то вам бы дали власть и вы бы продемостировали службу стакОверфлоу...

Comment: @Dev18 "власть" отредактировать ответ есть у каждого участника с репутацией выше пороговой. А вы почти переходите на личности.

Comment: Более того, у автора ответа есть "власть" не согласиться с такой правкой.

Comment: Так вот и интересно что это такое Qwertiy придумал и как оно должно функционировать? Потому как в принципе идея может быть и имеет здравое зерно, но кажется, что текущая реализация вызывает больше вопросов и проблем, чем пользы.

Comment: @Kromster ждём пост

Comment: @Nofate ваш ответ равносилен, что когда говорят===> у нас демократия)))), НО если имеющий статус сделает глупость/необоснованность/новизну без объяснений, все будут тихо обсуждать возможно даже в желтой прессе напишут максимум, а если смертный рабочий сделает тоже самое, его забьют.газом утихомерят и заставят впреть вести себя тихо и вообще сотрут может)))

Comment: я не вступаю в дисскусси, просто вышло уведомление, привекло внимание, и я увидела метку ```1 апреля``` ....к слову я уже несколько раз говорила, что неплохо бы добавить метку Syncfusion (она на англ сайте есть) и вообще если уж админ взялся за сайт, то неплохо бы следить за добавлением меток нужных юзерам, то есть к тому, что выходят новые платформы/языки/составные как к примеру Syncfusion, ну чтож что у них есть свой сайт, тут же тоже программисты сидят кто работал и знает данный компонент

Comment: как я заметила, вы изменили свой комментарий, я на личности никогда и ни при каких условиях точно не перехожу, ошибка, или угроза...даже не знаю как расценивать

Comment: @Dev18 у нас не демократия. У нас коммерческая компания со своими интересами, и волонтеры, которые в свое свободное время пытаются поддерживать жизнеспособное сообщество. Все аналогии с политикой и борьбой за власть уводят обсуждение в сомнительное русло.

Comment: тем более, если это коммерция, то когда вносят "новизну" (возможно удивящую пользователей), тут же добавляют пояснение/tuto, а не ждут вопросов и недопонятий)))

Comment: ...не достаточно написать хороший код, важно не забыть комментарии ))))цитаты великих людей

Comment: @Dev18 отчасти согласен, но это уже оффтопик. Касательно меток - их может создать каждый. Там порог толи очень низкий, толи вообще нету (непомню). Так что как только будут вопросы - метки "появятся сами".

Comment: @Kromster а самодеятельность запрещена? Всегда же можно сделать откат.

Comment: @Qwertiy прошло больше недели. Ждем ответ. Иначе буду снимать плашку правками )

Comment: @Kromster, блин, забыл... Вечером напишу.

Comment: @Qwertiy раз уж пообещали пост, то лучше напишите. Народ просит)

Comment: @Qwertiy до сих пор не ответил..) Или где-то блог-пост есть уже про это?

Comment: @PeterKolosov не ответил, но пост зачем-то пообещал.....

Comment: @Qwertiy мы всё ещё ждём

Comment: @Qwertiy у вас полярный день? ))

Comment: @Kromster "Плашки убрал" - то есть теперь незаконный ответ будет  находиться на сайте (его не удалили), но плашки о том, что это Gpt-шлак тоже не будет. По-моему, лучше было оставить плашки, ведь это лучше, чем ничего.

Comment: @Зонтик если вы считаете что ответ незаконен - ставьте тревогу. Если просто плох или неправилен - минус. Плашками замусоривать тут нечего )

Comment: @Kromster главный аргумент против плашек вроде был "если это gpt-ответы, то они недопустимы, и их надо удалить". Ответы не удалены, хотя этот пост 500+ раз посмотрели, то есть о существовании этих ответов знают точно три человека с репутацией 20k+. Но "предупреждения об опасности" убрали. И кстати, почему "замусоривать"? Разве gpt-ответы сами по себе - не мусор? А разве можно испортить мусор?

Comment: @Зонтик вы так пишете, будто у вас есть "безошибочный ChatGPT детектор" в купе с "безошибочным детектором неправильных ответов" ))

Comment: @Зонтик, ковид подхватил, у компа почти не был...

Comment: @Qwertiy ого, уже месяц и даже больше прошло

Comment: Кажется, скоро к чему-то такому и придём: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396626/309650.

Answer (score 10):

Выскажу свое мнение:

**Плашки убрать. Если модератор не уверен, от ChatGPT этот ответ или нет - не трогать его.**

Плашки совершенно вырвиглазные, и главное ненужные. У нас уже есть механизм контроля качества - минусы и комментарии.

Если *подозреваете*, что это сгенерировано ChatGPT - оставьте комментарий про это. Если ответ при этом плохой - ставьте минус и/или голосуйте за удаление.

Comment: Ответы от chatgpt почти наверняка. Оба пользователя с этими плашками получили за свои ответы бан.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тогда почему они не удалены, если ChatGPT явно запрещен правилами?

Comment: А если модератор *уверен*, что это gpt?

Comment: @Qwertiy все еще ждем вашего разъяснения ситуации .. (ответов на вопросы в посте)

Comment: @Зонтик Удалены, конечно, согласно [вот этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy). Я сначала так понял, что модератор удалил те, про которые был уверен; а про которые не уверен - отметил плашкой. Если вдруг он выбирал не так, а по качеству ответов - это еще более сомнительно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Проясните, как вы выбирали, какие ответы удалить, а на какие навесить плашку?

Answer (score 5):

***Дисклеймер:** я совершенно согласен с [принятой политикой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) в отношении ответов, сгенерированных ботами. Никаким образом, прямо или косвенно не пытаюсь её поставить под сомнение или оспорить. Мой ответ скорее про сообщения низкого качества, и что с ними возможно сделать, а не конкретно про ответы ботов.*

Раз уж я тут собрался в модераторы, попробую не пройти мимо. От меня обработано около 5 флагов за ChatGPT-шные ответы низкого качества. Все такие сообщения участников удалены.

У ChatGPT есть отличительные особенности: особая манера изложения и машинное мышление при составлении ответа на основе семантики текста в вопросе, а не на основе его смысла. А так как большинство новичков умудряются задавать свои вопросы так, что даже мне (в моей любимой метка `С#`) они не понятны, то куда уж там боту разобраться. Больше половины GPT-шных ответов - это 100% промах, остальные частично попадают.

Расстраивают эти ответы в первую очередь тем, что вводят в заблуждение автора вопроса, влияют на его отношение к StackOverflow. И еще хуже, когда автор вопроса не особо разбираясь в ответе, ставит галку и идет дальше. Тогда в базе знаний оседает принятый ответ, имеющий бесполезный контент. Это нехорошо и слегка вредит StackOverflow.

Флагал я такие ответы не потому что они написаны ботом, а потому что они именно плохие. Ставил минус, голосовал за удаление и ставил флаг. Ответы, в которых я сомневался, оставлял без внимания.

---

Считаю, что такая метка - спорное решение. Это в первую очередь указывает на то что StackOverflow содержит сомнительный контент, мы это знаем, и ничего с этим не делаем или не можем сделать. Как говорят, в таких случаях надо "либо крестик снять, либо трусы надеть". Не стоит останавливаться на таких надписях.

Вариантов решений, которые мне по душе, несколько:

1. Оставить как было, удалять плохой GPT, оставлять сомнительный и хороший.
2. Раз уж на то пошло, доработать систему маркировки так, чтобы она не была доступна автору ответа, подобно тем плашкам, которыми помечаются закрытые или защащенные вопросы.

**Например**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И прикрутить данную активность к очереди "Сообщения низкого качества". Сделать систему аналогичную закрытию и переоткрытию вопроса.

Сама отметка никак не должна ограничивать редактуру. Это просто синяя плашка, которая ни на что не влияет, а только содержит информацию.

---

*Другими словами, сфокусироваться стоит не на ответах, сгенерированных ботами, а именно на их качестве, независимо от природы появления.*

Comment: Но ведь [уже договорились](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy), что нельзя оставлять ответы ChatGPT

Comment: @nomnoms12 моё мнение здесь никак не конфликтует с решениями, принятыми ранее. А потом время идет, боты умнеют. Кто знает, может GPT4 будет ответы лучше давать, ну и прочие нюансы следует учитывать в будущем. Этот пост про некачественный контент, а не про ChatGPT.

Comment: Одно из ваших предложений — оставлять ответы ChatGPT. При том, что это недопустимо

Comment: @nomnoms12 вы когда-нибудь видели сообщение, явно сгенерированное ботом, но отвечающее на вопрос автора? Я видел. Потом, если ответ правильный, то какие проблемы он вызывает? Доказать, что автор такого ответа не имеет должных компетенций, невозможно, а следовательно и причин для удаления такого ответа нет.

Comment: Правильный ответ, сгенерированный ChatGPT, вызывает, как минимум, проблемы лицензирования

Comment: Но лично мне более важной кажется проблема потери доверия к сообществу. Если бы я хотел ответ от ChatGPT, то у него бы и спросил

Comment: @nomnoms12 кем бы код не был сгенерирован, ответственность за его публикацию несет автор ответа, а не StackOverflow. Такое чувство, что вы нашли где-то во мне защитника GPT-шных ответов и пытаетесь меня переубедить или переспорить. Так вот, нет во мне такого защитника, вам показалось.

Comment: Если пользователь публикует спам, мы удаляем спам. Если пользователь публикует ответ ChatGPT, мы должны удалить ответ ChatGPT. Потому что нельзя публиковать спам. И нельзя публиковать ChatGPT

Comment: Вы предлагает нарушать наши же правила. И спрашиваете у меня, какие проблемы это вызывает

Comment: @nomnoms12 обновите страницу.

Comment: @nomnoms12 мы должны удалять, но не удаляем. Я же в своём ответе приводил пример участника, который дал 22 таких ответа,, и из них удалили только 2.

Comment: @nomnoms12 Поэтому пока такие плашки. Если будем удалять ответы, то и плашки будут не нужны =)

Comment: Кстати, почему вы считаете, что синяя рамка должна быть видна только высокореповым участникам? В чём тогда её смысл? 99% заходящих приходят из гугла, они могут даже аккаунтов не меть.

Comment: @Зонтик как можно вообще было вот так понять ответ? Нет, я так не считаю.

Comment: @aepot *И прикрутить данную активность к очереди "Сообщения низкого качества"* - если я верно понял, то участники с репутацией 2K+ видят в очереди плашки о том, что ответ некачественный (пока что не про chatGPT).  Ну и сокрытие от автора мне тоже не нравится.

Comment: @Зонтик скрытие от автора - возможность убрать плашку, а не саму плашку. Видеть ее конечно же должны все участники, иначе смысл в этом какой? Сейчас где модераторы подписывают ответы, как указанно в вопросе, автор может отредактировать ответ убрав сообщение модератора. Я об этом. Видимо действительно мой пост кривой, вы прочитали в нем неправильно примерно всё.

Answer (score -1):

Правильность `gpt`-ответов неоднозначна, и из-за их размытости и жонглирования словами, словосочетаниями и предложениями очень сложно понять, насколько ответ верен или неверен, это надо прямо очень хорошо в него вчитываться.

И так, `gpt`-ответы могут быть *правильными* (редко); *частично правильными, а частично неверными (чаще всего)*; *в корне неверными* (тоже довольно часто). **И нет ничего плохого в том, что есть человек, который готов потратить свои силы и время на сортировку этого шлака**.

И не забывайте, что на данный момент есть много ответов, которые **точно** сгенерированы с помощью `gpt`. И не все из них удаляются. [Вот пример gpt-пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/540296/andrei-popruha). О том, что он gpt-шник, [очевидно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12327/%d0%a3%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-22-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-70-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-c?rq=1). Но лишь два из множества его ответов были удалены. **И реально круто, если они будут так сортироваться**.

Кстати, преимущество такого подхода в том, что читающий **сразу видит предупреждение об опасности**. А то комментарии не все читают, да и видишь их тольоко в самом конце. К тому же  комментарии - вещь втроростепенная, они могут быть в любой момент удалены или перемещены в чат.

**P.S.** ИМХО, тег [модераторский-произвол](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb) здесь лишний. Если вам это так не нравиться, всегда можно откатить (хотя я бы этого не стал делать). И модераторским произволом это было бы тогда, если бы кто-то сделал откат, а модератор бы делал многочисленные переоткаты.

#### **Дополнение:**

Я не говорю, что такие ответы не должны удаляться. Должны. Но пока это не так. Дело в том, что за час можно запостить 20  таких "ответов". "Героев" в последнее время очень много, и уже просто не хватает сил на удаление `gpt`-шлака. На данный момент даже треть этого шлака не удаляется.

#### **Про действия модератора:**

Я не против плашек, но вижу, что сообществу они не понравились (их уже убрали). Вроде бы всё ясно, но `@Qwertiy` пообещал "вечером" написать какой-то пост. Вот только поста 2 недели нет. ИМХО, так делать не стоило, а сейчас стоит либо сказать "поста не будет", либо написать пост.

#### **На текущий момент:**

Я очень огорчён ситуацией на данный момент. Вместо того чтобы удалить ответы, с них сняли плашки. У этого поста 500+ просмотров, а на мету не так уж и часто заходят пользователи-однодневки. То есть сюда точно зашло хотя бы 3 пользователя, которые могут проголосовать за удаление тех ответов. Но всё что сделали - убрали "предупреждения об опасности".

Comment: Тег добавил я )
Потому что этот старый добрый тег согласно описанию "про случаи самоуправства со стороны модераторов" по мнению участников. Он тут вполне уместен.

Comment: [модераторский-произвол] тут вполне уместен, так как это деятельность одного отдельно взятого модератора, не согласованная ни с кем (ждем его поста, может быть все не так - тогда плашку снимем).

Comment: А краткое описание создал я :)

Comment: @Kromster ну мы пока не знаем, может модераторы там у себя что-то и согласовали. Чем они там в своих закрытых чатах занимаются страшно представить даже.

Comment: а минус зонтику за что и кто поставил

Comment: *...закрытых чатах занимаются страшно представить даже.* @αλεχολυτ а вы нам расскажете, когда станете ?

Comment: @Dev18 на мете  (**не путать с основным сайтом!**) на ответы на вопросы с меткой [обсуждение]  ставят минусы, если не согласны с изложенным мнением. **На основном сайте это, конечно, не так, там вообще ответов-мнений не должно быть, там минусуют за неточность/неверность ответа**

Comment: @Dev18 разве может модератор выдавать тайны модераторской важности )

Comment: @Dev18 это Мета, тут могут и на ... минус послать!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ все, или только модераторы ?)

Comment: @Dev18 ну... каждый может стать модератором, поэтому, я бы сказал, что все.

Comment: *"человек ... сортировку этого шлака"* И что, мы будем считать мнение одного человека за мнение всего сообщества? Плюсы и минусы нужны для того, чтобы получать усредненное общее мнение, а тут один человек единолично решает, какой ответ хороший, а какой плохой.

Comment: "не хватает сил на удаление gpt-шлака" - выглядит как задачка подходящая для нейросети :-)