# Так ответил ChatGPT

Tags: обсуждение, генеративный-ии

[Сам ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1517720/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3/1517743#1517743)

Если ответ верен с точки зрения самого вопроса. (речь не конкретно о вышеуказанном ответе, в общем и целом)

Ставить +? Тревогу? ChatGPT Запрещен или нет на so или рекомендован к не использованию? А если ответ через gtp все таки окажется верным(о чудо), и помог решить задачу?

UPD: Он мне попался в проверках. И я не понимаю, мне тревожиться, или все нормально?

Comment: ChatGPT запрещён, ответ нужно удалить. Можете поставить тревогу

Comment: @nomnoms12, как то упустил ваш комментарий. Благодарю, и в будущем буду иметь ввиду.

Comment: imho к chatGPT надо относиться как к любому поисковику. Оценивать нужно конкретно ответ. Если ответ нормальный - плюсуйте, если не нравится -- ставьте минус

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. СhatGPT **запрещён** на сайте.

   - [Страница из справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)
   - [Обсуждение на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/)
2. Ответы, сгененированые `gpt`, должны удаляться вне зависимости от их содержания (ведь они недопустимы). Пока, к сожалению, большинство продолжает висеть на сайте.
3. Бороться с `gpt`-ответами **нужно**. Есть несколько способов, как это можно сделать:

   - от 15 баллов репутации - поставить [тревогу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) "Требует вмешательство модератора" и написать, что это gpt (желательно ещё добавить, почему, например: участник даёт длинные ответы раз в 3-5 минут по различным языкам программирования).
   - от 20 баллов репутации - кинуть ссылку на подозрительного пользователя в [чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).
   - от 50 баллов репутации (если gpt-ответ дали на ваш вопрос - то от 1) - написать [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) под ответом с сcылкой на [страницу справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) (можно ещё добавить ссылку на [обсуждение на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/), там намного подробней описан смысл запрета).
   - от 125 балов репутации - [проголосовать "против"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).
   - от 20k репутации - [проголосовать за удаление ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

И ещё рекомендую просмотреть все посты с меткой [gpt](/questions/tagged/gpt), в некоторых их них говорилось, почему `gpt`-ответы - это плохо, в некоторых - про борьбу с ними.

Comment: Я согласен с большинством мнений по поводу (не)использования chatGPT. Вопрос стоял что мне с подобным делать? Ваш ответ вполне меня устроил. Причина Дубликата мне не понятна. Если бы я хотел почитать чужое мнение по поводу использования gpt я бы не стал задавать вопросов. В дубликате же нахожу только мысли и рассуждения по поводу "почему это плохо" или "почему я против".

Comment: @1001001 думаю, что закрыли как дубль из-за этого: *Запрещен или нет на so или рекомендован к не использованию? А если ответ через gtp все таки окажется верным(о чудо), и помог решить задачу?*

Comment: ну понятно) в любом случае, спс