# Бастовать будем?

Tags: обсуждение

[Забастовка модераторов Stack Overflow](https://habr.com/ru/articles/741280/).
Поддержим?

Comment: Можно бастовать немного по-другому: просто игнорировать запрет на удаление  gpt-мусора.

Comment: Я не чувствую никакого вовлечения в процесс. Сама идея фильтровать ответы про происхождению противоречит требованию фильтровать ответы по качеству. Однажды наступит такой день, когда нейросеть начнёт давать ответы лучшие по качеству чем это делают большинство экспертов. Что тогда делать модераторам? Просто удалять хорошие ответы? Нонсенс.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy мне кажется для бездушных качественных ответов есть гугление. Пока лаконичность по качеству значительно опережает генерируемую простыню.

Comment: @DiMithras, именно что пока. Со временем нейросети заменят и поиск и большинство ответов на SO.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy на мой взгляд, мутные перспективы. Но 15 лет назад никто не думал, что будем тыкать пальцем в экраны телефонов, никто кроме пионеров с КПК. iPhone, на мой взгляд, выстрелил благодаря ёмкостному экрану, т.к. с резистивным было много проблем. К чему я с этой аналогией. Сейчас появилось множество пионеров в LLM, а качественного скачка не произошло. Безусловно большинство ответов заменит, особенно на вопросах вроде "*для чего нужен `print()`*" в Python, к сожалению вопросов низкого качества много, но по хитрым, мне приятнее читать ваши рассуждения, чем генеративную простыню.

Comment: Также в ноябре проблема была в том, что GPT начали использовать для набивки рейтинга. Если для GPT ответов будет обособленный сервисный аккаунт — без проблем. Целями сообщества будет либо одобрить такой ответ, либо написать лучше. Когда же выдают желаемое за действительно, это проблемка.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а как нейросеть начнет давать ответы лучше экспертов, если ее ответы базируются на ответах этих самых экспертов? Не будет ответов экспертов, не будет ответов нейросети.

Comment: @Эникейщик видимо речь про перспективное будущее, где [История одного байта](https://habr.com/ru/articles/27055/) будет решаться за пару секунд, и не будет потреблять литры пива.

Comment: @Эникейщик, пусть нейросеть не сможет выдать новый контент (это спорно, но пусть). Даже тогда нейросети годятся, скажем, для покрытия документации примерами. Вроде ответов на вопросы типа "для чего в Питоне enumerate". Воспринимайте нейросеть как трактор с помощью которого вы сможете вспахать куда больший кусок земли чем руками. ...

Comment: @Эникейщик, ...  Я enumerate не зря привел пример. Это такой вопрос, который может привлечь сюда много начинающих разработчиков. Но таких вопросов надо много. Буквально надо покрыть примерами всю стандартную библиотеку. Вот для такого типа вопросов/ответов нейросети могут оказаться незаменимыми. Получим много хороших ответов на простые вопросы, получим большое сообщество, получим некоторое количество интересных вопросов от сообщества, получим качественные ответы от спецов. Но в основании пирамиды должно быть много ответов на простые вопросы.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy пример с `enumerate` лучше чем с `print`, но в моём случае это ирония была. Так пусть на такие вопросы пишет ответы сервисный аккаунт, или предлагает решение вопроса на этапе написания вопроса. Поселить LLM вместе с людьми немного бьёт по сообществу, вам так не кажется? К тому же к чему хотят прийти, чтобы нейронка обучалась на сгенерированных ответах? Так себе рекурсия.

Comment: Если кто как и я долго искал саму форму, вот она: https://openletter.mousetail.nl/

Comment: Вопрос не в конкретном сайте, увы. А вообще смотрю на все это так же, как на постоянные реформы науки и образования: как хорошо, что уже пенсия, и новые времена, когда ум и знания ничего не стоят, приходят без меня. Да, следующие поколения жалко, но и динозаврам, наверное, тоже не хотелось вымирать :) Простите за прямоту, но, глядя на уровень современных студентов в наших странах, я вижу, что ИИ и в самом деле отличный выбор — как минимум превосходящий по уровню знаний. А мотивации их получать пока что и у ИИ, и у студентов одинаковы и по сути нулевые.

Comment: @Harry спору нет, мир летит в тартарары. Но [этот комментарий](https://habr.com/ru/articles/741280/comments/#comment_25641854) на хабре [и этот](https://habr.com/ru/articles/741280/#comment_25642994) объясняют недовольство. Никто не против прогресса, все против откровенного мусора, который запретили удалять.

Comment: @DiMithras Знаете, есть такая поговорка — "сгорел сарай — гори и хата". Толку пытаться вытянуть отдельно взятый ruSO, который, будем откровенны, летит в те же тартарары уже несколько последних лет...

Comment: @DiMithras "долго искал саму форму" - в статье, ссылка на которую есть в вопросе, есть ссылка на это письмо бастующих =)

Comment: Кстати, один из наших модераторов подписал письмо о забастовке: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRJeh.png

Comment: Может метку [meta-tag:важное] добавить пора?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Провокационный вопрос, но мне скрывать нечего. Так как я уже [писал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12759/373567), что изменение политики ничего не меняет в принятии мной решений при модерации, то ни в каких забастовках смысла не вижу.

Впрочем, это дело каждого. Моя задача как модератора в том, чтобы участникам было комфортно задавать вопросы и отвечать на них. Удаляя весь без разбору GPT, в том числе неявный, я могу зацепить случайно живого автора. Оставляя весь GPT, в том числе самый неадекватный, я рискую превратить сайт в мусорку типа третьей страницы поисковой выдачи гугла, куда никто не заглядывает.

Смысл протестов глобального сообщества в том, что администрация не смогла вывести формулу, по которой можно конкретно и однозначно определить критерий принятия решения, кто писал контент для каждого ответа, робот или человек, и из крайности "строго мочить всё" перешла в другую крайность "строго забить на всё". Но с моей точки зрения, ни та не другая крайность не отведёт нас в светлое будущее, а скорее навредит сообществу.

Как я рассматривал GPT-ответы исключительно с точки зрения качества контента, а не их происхождения, так и буду рассматривать. И вам тоже так делать советую.

По поводу забастовки, я отчасти солидарен с бастующими и понимаю их. Они как раз и переживают за то самое светлое будущее. И честно говоря, компания Stack Exchange могла донести свои решения более конструктивно, нежели в виде свода команд и политик, выйти на конструктивный диалог, хотя бы попытаться.

Сайты сети SE по своей природе построены вокруг сообществ, и игнорирование наличия этих сообществ при принятии решений по управлению такими сайтами, по меньшей мере абсурд. Тем более тогда, когда сообщества бьют в колокол и прямым текстом заявляют о своём несогласии с происходящими событиями.

Оставлять SE в режиме "бить всех роботов" определённо было нельзя, это была острая проблема, которую срочно надо было решать. Идея ясна. А вот исполнение, на мой взгляд подкачало.

Мы же с вами умеем думать своей головой, принимая те или иные решения при создании и модерации контента, верно? Вот давайте пока этим и займёмся. Надеюсь, компания и сообщества SE придут к тому самому конструктивному диалогу и согласию. Всем добра.

Comment: Я не модератор, конечно, но выскажу свое мнение в комментариях. Не понимаю зачем удалять GPT ответы если они решают проблему? Бастовать? Это же по сути то же самое, что удалить ответ учасника, если он "нагуглил" решение. 

Как это науглдивание определить? Плохо ли то, что ответ по сути взят из Интернета? Считаю, что нет, ведь и тот кто задавал вопрос, обучится полезному из ответа, и тот кто отвечал тоже. И база знаний пополнится. Спрашивать у бота просто быстрее, чем у гугла, так в чем разница? (Если, конечно, код у бота рабочий). Может быть я не прав, я сам ботом не пользовался еще.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH не думаю, что ситуация SO как-то отличается от ситуации на Тостере, а там ответы нейросеток мусорные, они не только не помогают, но ещё и больше в заблуждение вводят. И даже если бы они были хоть немного качественными, возможность прокачивать рейтинг для любого, способного обратиться к боту, автоматически приведёт к исходу с ресурса экспертов.

Answer (score 7):

Здесь уже дан один ответ, и этот ответ дан очень известным и уважаемым человеком.

я хочу только дополнить его ответ, явным образом указав на последствия разрешения ИИ - контента:

в этом случае после того, как вы задаёте вопрос в течение нескольких секунд у вас под вопросом будет появляться ответ... от попугая. Ответ, который ни на что не отвечает, а просто льёт воду.

Довольно быстро у участников выработается аналог "баннерной слепоты": после задавания вопроса - на первый ответ вообще не смотреть. Ждать, когда придут люди и напишут, *может быть*, второй ответ.

Как то так. я бы поучаствовал в забастовке. GPT - штука, которая реально портит жизнь.