# Аккаунт для общих GPT-ответов

Tags: обсуждение, генеративный-ии

Недавно появился участник [GPT-Answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/557946/gpt-answer), который создаёт общие ответы, сгенерированные ChatGPT, что он, правда, честно указывает ([пример ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1526257/507426)). Хотелось бы узнать мнение сообщества по этому поводу.

Comment: Вообще-то он создал всего 1 ответ. Я не против, если такой аккаунт будет отвечать, если владелец будет фильтровать чушь. Но лучше если бы это был не чей-то акк, а например бот, встроенный в сайт, ответ которого мог бы запросить сам автор, если вопрос например имеет положительный баланс голосов. Или/и автор имеет достаточно репутации.

Comment: Ответы этого участника - удалить; самого участника - в бан.

Comment: А смысл? Зачем копипастить сюда то, что каждый и так на ChatGPT может сам получить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему публикация ответов, созданных GPT и ChatGPT, недопустима?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-gpt-%d0%b8-chatgpt-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0)

Comment: [Мнение сообщества по этому поводу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-gpt-%d0%b8-chatgpt-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0)

Comment: Аккаунт уже потерли

Answer (score 1):

1. Публикация gpt-ответов [запрещена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).
2. Это подаёт плохой пример новым пользователем.
3. Понятие "не сложные вопросы" очень субьективное.

Вывод: Ответы этого участника - удалить; самого участника - в бан.

Comment: На MSE какую-то забастовку подняли вроде бы из-за того, что как раз GPT-ответы теперь нельзя так просто удалять.

Comment: @PeterKolosov В соответствии с новой политикой можно удалять Gpt-посты, если автор сам признаёт, что это gpt. Ведь компания боится, что модераторы могут ошибиться и забанить невинного. А тут он сам признаётся, так что всё ок.

Comment: А, окей, понял.

Comment: Не правильное решение. Очень похоже, что к ChatGPT пора уже относиться как к разновидности поисковика, например, google. Вы же не пытаетесь запретить ответы, информация для которых получена через google? Так и с GPT, надо оценивать **содержание ответа**, а не инструмент, которым создан текст ответа

Comment: @avp тоже считаю неправильным решением. Ранее, как раз, [предлагал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12778/Бастовать-будем#comment55594_12778) такой аккаунт сделать.

Comment: @avp наше мнение компанию не интересует.